# Synch eos rp and flash speedlite 430exII, godox x1t 2.4g

Tags: canon, hotshoe-flash, godox, canon-ex430ii

I have canon eos rp and flash speedlite 430exII, ive purchased godox x1t 2.4g but not able to synchronise the flashing, pls help.. can anybody help me to sort it out pls

Comment: Your question needs more clarity. Are you using both a Godox compatible radio transmitter and receiver?

Comment: I'm using canon speedlite exit as flash and bought godox x1tc trigger, but not able to synch with my canon eos rp cam..

Comment: You need to buy a Godox X1R-C receiver and attach it to the flash.

Comment: Will x1r-c synch with canon speedlite?

Comment: Yes, the X1R-C will “sync” or communicate with your Canon Speedlite.

Comment: Thank u very much, I will try

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make my speedlight, a Canon 430EX II work wirelessly with my Godox gear?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/115032/how-can-i-make-my-speedlight-a-canon-430ex-ii-work-wirelessly-with-my-godox-gea)

Comment: Hi I purchased x1r-c, can u pls guide how to synch the same.

Comment: Kindly help me  please

Answer (score 2):

If you want to control the 430EX II via radio, you need to connect a compatible *radio* receiver to the hot foot of the flash. The only wireless capability the 430EX II has own its own is *optical* wireless control using Canon's optical wireless protocol.

The Godox X1R-C is the only radio receiver not built into a Godox flash that I'm aware of that is compatible with all of Godox's 2.4GHz transmitters, such as your X1T-C.